# Comparison Methods

Tags: java, methods

I am doing an assignment for my intro to java class that requires the use of methods to convert temperatures from Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa. It requires the use of three comparison methods and I cannot figure out what to put in them. These are the instructions:

three comparison methods:

`public boolean equals (Temperature other)` – This method will take the other temperature as a parameter and return true if the calling object has the same temperature as other, false otherwise. Note that a Celsius temperature can be equal to a Fahrenheit temperature as indicated by the above formulas.

`public boolean lessThan (Temperature other)` – This method will return true if the calling object’s temperature is less than the other, false otherwise.

`public boolean greaterThan (Temperature other)` – This method will return true if the calling object’s temperature is greater than the other, false otherwise.

And this is all I have so far as I am not sure how to start this:

```
public boolean equals (Temperature other) 
{
    // code here
}
public boolean lessThan (Temperature other) 
{
    // code here
}
public boolean greaterThan (Temperature other) 
{
    // code here
}
```

I am very new to java so I apologize if this a very obvious answer. Please help, thank you!

Comment: Does the class `Temperature` have an attribute that determines its scale (Celsius/Fahrenheit/Kelvin)? You would have to check if the current instance and the `other` one have the same scale or not.

Comment: Something like `if this.temperature > other.getTemperature()`

Comment: Could you show us the code of the class `Temperature`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would personally do (assuming that the Temperature class can be EITHER Celsius OR Fahrenheit. Is make a method to convert the given scale to a predefined one. For instance, if you have a class with Celsius and a class with Fahrenheit its easiest to convert either the Celsius one to Fahrenheit or vice versa so you can easily compare the two. Of course the one with the right value doesn't need conversion.

After you've done this you can use the converted value to compare the two temperatures.

It looks something like this:

```
public float toCelsius() {
    switch (scale) {
        case "celsius":
            return temperature;
        case "fahrenheit":
            return (temperature - 32) / 1.8;
    }
    return 0;
}

public boolean equals (Temperature other) {
    return toCelsius() == other.toCelsius();
}
```

Note: To make this cleaner you could add an enumeration for the scales, for example purposes I didn't do this and since the person asking the question is new I'm assuming they don't have to. Just keep in mind that adding an enumeration would be a much cleaner method of executing the switch case AND storing the scale.